# What are my options for Augmented Reality plane detection in a hybrid app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, augmented-reality, hybrid-mobile-app

I am looking at incorporating some AR functionality into a Ionic/Cordova app and have looked extensively into different potential solutions without any luck. The AR feature must support plane detection (marker-less) as we want to place an object on a flat surface (a ceiling).

Would this even be possible in Cordova?

I have looked into Wikitudes offering, which unfortunately does not support plane detection within their Javascript API ([link](https://www.wikitude.com/products/native-and-js-api-comparison/))

I have also looked into other webview options such as 'AR.js' + Aframe and '8thWall', which not only do they not support Plane detection, they also might not fully work within Cordova.

**Essentially**, after spending many hours looking into it. I'm wondering if what I want is even possible without native development?

Answer (score 0):

Without native development you can indeed try 8th Wall. You can use it through Unity (8thWall XR) or through web, both support plan detection (but it works better when arkit/arcore is supported on the device).

AR.js only support target detection for now.

Otherwise you can also have a look at AR Foundation on Unity.